# Fresnel and Emission

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shader-nodes

I have a fresnel node connected to an emission shader, but I need to boost the resulting value. I assume I need a multiplier between the two.

[image]

I want it to glow as the first sphere (A glow filter is applied on the compositor). That material has strength of 20.

**What node can I add to boost the strength keeping the fresnel?**

Comment: You basically answered your question, you could use a math node to multiply the fresnel or use the fresnel as a factor for the emission and control the emission strength manually

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Math nodes for this. Many maths operations can increase the brightness in various ways. Multiply will work, but if you want to control the contrast, you can use power as well:

[image]